# Double has_many attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm beginner in rails and having trouble finding a proper way out with my problem.

I have three models : Conversation, participant, messages which have the following attributes :

Conversation :

```
module Messenger
  class Conversation <ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :participants, :class_name => 'Messenger::Participant'

    def messages
      self.participants.messages.order(:created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

Participant :

```
module Messenger

  class Participant <ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :messages, :class_name => 'Messenger::Message'

    belongs_to :conversation, :class_name => 'Messenger::Conversation'

  end
end
```

Message :

```
module Messenger

  class Message <ActiveRecord::Base

    default_scope {order(:created_at)}
    default_scope {where(deleted: false)}

    belongs_to :participant, :class_name => 'Messenger::Participant'

  end
end
```

My trouble is that I'm trying to make a single form to create a conversation with a first message in it. The form looks like this :

```
= form_for @conversation, url: messenger.conversations_create_path do |f|
  .row
    .col-md-12.no-padding
      .whitebg.padding15
        .form-group.user-info-block.required
          = f.label :title, t('trad'), class: 'control-label'
          = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

        .form-group.user-info-block.required
          = f.label :model, t('trad'), class: 'control-label'
          = f.text_field :model, class: 'form-control'

        .form-group.user-info-block.required
          = f.label :model_id, t('trad'), class: 'control-label'
          = f.text_field :model_id, class: 'form-control'

        = fields_for @message, @conversation.participants.message do |m|
          = m.label :content, t('trad'), class: 'control-label'
          = m.text_area :content, class:'form-control'

  .user-info-block.action-buttons
    = f.submit t('trad'), :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-right'
```

I've tried many ways to make this form simple but I've encountered some problems which I don't know how to fix using rails properly.

I've tried using `Field_for`to include a message in my conversation form, but since I have nothing saved in my database yet it seems I can't link a message to an unexisting participant.

So basically I want my first form, once validated, to create a conversation, link the current user to that conversation and link the message to that first user, but I assume there are ways to do it with the framework and I would not like to do it manually.

What is the proper way to follow to achieve that? Am I even on the good track or shoould I change something or add something?

Edit : to make it more understandable, a participant got a user_id and a conversation_id, which means this is a relation table. I can't adapt the attributes of my models to make it easier since I must keep it in that way for security reasons.

Comment: you may want to look at has_many through association for messages in Conversation instead of your hand-rolled method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, in order for your form to accept nested attributes using the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-Nested+Attributes+Examples) form helper, you need to specify [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) on your `Conversation` model:

```
module Messenger
  class Conversation <ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :participants, :class_name => 'Messenger::Participant'

    # Required for form helper
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants

    [...]
```

Since you want to save a both `Participant` as well as its `Message` from the same form, you need to add a second `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on your `Participant` model:

```
module Messenger

  class Participant <ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :messages, :class_name => 'Messenger::Message'

    # Required for form helper
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages

    belongs_to :conversation, :class_name => 'Messenger::Conversation'

  end
end
```

**Next**, in your controller, since this is a new `Conversation` that doesn't have any `Participant`s at first, you need to [`build`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build) an associated `Participant` (presumably based on the `current_user`), and also an associated `Message` for this new `Participant`:

```
def new
  @conversation.participants.build(user: current_user).messages.build
end
```

**Finally** in your view, specify the attribute fields in three nested blocks, `form_for @conversation do |f|`, `f.fields_for :participants do |p|`, and `p.fields_for :messages do |m|`:

```
= form_for @conversation, url: messenger.conversations_create_path do |f|
  [...]
  = f.fields_for :participants do |p|
    = p.fields_for :messages do |m|
      = m.label :content, t('trad'), class: 'control-label'
      = m.text_area :content, class:'form-control'

  .user-info-block.action-buttons
    = f.submit t('trad'), :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-right'
```

---

Side note: the (incorrectly implemented) `messages` method in `Conversation` should be replaced by a simple [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relation:

```
has_many :messages, through: :participants
```

Comment: Well, Thank you a million times, that's the result I was looking for, and indeed the through keyword is a big improvement for my code. Worked perfectly, accepted !

Answer (score 2):

Message needs to `belong_to` Conversation directly, since you need to disambiguate when participants have more than one conversation.

So having done that, you can build the conversation's default message in the controller using

```
@conversation.messages.build(participant: @conversation.participants.first)
```

That's pretty wordy, so you can add a couple of model methods to reduce the controller call to

```
@conversation.build_default_message
```

In this case, you want to create a Conversation, but it needs to create a Message with user input as well. So Conversation needs to accept attributes on behalf of Message. You can do that using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Conversation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end
```

This would allow you to create a Conversation with 1 or more associated Messages using

```
Conversation.create(
  ..., 
  messages_attributes: [
    { participant_id: 1, content: 'question' } 
  ]
)
```

Comment: We've defined our model like this and can't link a message directly in a converstion for security reasons, this is why I need to keep models like that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think, you have mistakes in this method:

```
def messages
  self.participants.messages.order(:created_at)
end
```

since `Conversation` `has_many :participants`:

`self.participants` will return an array, not a single `Participant` active record object. So you can't directly call `messages` on an array. You need to iterate that array and call `messages` on each object.

Use nested form and `fields_for` method and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (you can find how to write these from SO or documentation) and post the code code and error what you got. Then someone might be able to help you.

And to use `fields_for`:

Since you can't link a message directly to a `Conversation` and you need a message field, you need to link a `@message` to any participant. you can build a `Participant` from `current_user` or first user i.e `User.first` for the `@conversation` and then build a `@message` for this `Participant`.